# How do a question's and answer's score affect its rankings in SO's search results?

Tags: support, search

How do a question's and answer's score affect its rankings in SO's search results? And how does an answer's score affect its position within a given question?

Generally, what is the scoring system for questions that ranks it during search?

Comment: Your question was kinda unfocused, Neil. I've edited it; feel free to edit further if I haven't captured your intent. In particular, it wasn't clear if you cared about answer ranking, as well as question ranking, and you *might* have been talking about the reputation of the post's authors, rather than the score of the post itself.

Comment: Yup. I also care about answer ranking. Basically what I just wanted to ask is during a user's search for answers, how does SO return search results and how does it rank them. @MichaelPetrotta